# PHP/MySQL - reorder a numerical sequence when changing a value

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, tree

I'm working on an application which stores a tree in a database. The application is built using CakePHP 2.x and jstree 3.2.1

The schema for saving the data is as follows:

- `id` - auto increment ID, unique for each node of the tree
- `parent_id` - the parent ID for an element; `null` if no parent (top level element).
- `lft`, `rght` - Using CakePHP's [Tree Behaviour](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html) which uses  [Modified Preorder Tree Traversal](https://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/). These represent the `lft` and `rght` values.
- `name` - text name of the node
- `pos` - an integer which starts from 0 to determine the position of a node under its parent.

The problem I'm having is "adjusting" all of the `pos` elements when updates are made to the position of a node in the tree.

For example, consider the following data:

```
id    |    parent_id    |    name    |     pos
--------------------------------------------------
149   |    NULL         |    Foo     |     0
150   |    149          |    A       |     0
151   |    149          |    B       |     1
152   |    149          |    C       |     2
153   |    149          |    D       |     3
154   |    149          |    E       |     4
155   |    149          |    F       |     5
```

Visually, this looks as follows:

- Foo

  - A
  - B
  - C
  - D
  - E
  - F

Now if I was to drag-and-drop "E" so it is between "B" and "C"...

- Foo

  - A
  - B
  - E (**moved**)
  - C
  - D
  - F

... I need to update the `pos` value in my database, for everything that is a child of "Foo".

When the drag-and-drop occurs, jstree provides me with:

1. The `id` of the element I've moved. "E" would be `154`.
2. The `parent_id` that "E" has been dropped under. In this case it's `149` because it's still a child of "Foo", but could in theory be moved under any other element on the tree.
3. The `pos` (position) that it has been dropped in. These start at 0, so in the above example after "E" is moved it is in `pos = 2`.

*It's important to understand that nodes can be dragged in either direction - up or down - but jstree will only ever provide the `pos` in relation to where it is under a parent node (as well as `parent_id` and `id`).*

So I can update my database with the new `pos` for "E":

```
>UPDATE tree SET pos = 2 WHERE id = 154 AND parent_id = 149;

id    |    parent_id    |    name    |     pos
--------------------------------------------------
149   |    NULL         |    Foo     |     0
150   |    149          |    A       |     0
151   |    149          |    B       |     1
152   |    149          |    C       |     2
153   |    149          |    D       |     3
154   |    149          |    E       |     2 (*updated*)
155   |    149          |    F       |     5
```

The problem I have is how to re-arrange the other `pos` values. For example, "C" should now have a `pos` value of `4`.

There is some code on GitHub which shows [an example of how the data is saved when a node is moved](https://github.com/vakata/jstree-php-demos/blob/master/sitebrowser/class.tree.php#L216), but I cannot follow this (despite days of going through it) or adapt it to CakePHP. Indeed, much of the code provided is un-necessary because Cake takes care of generating the `lft` and `rght` values. So what I want to know is **how do I "shift" or "adjust" numbers back into a numerical sequence** with PHP/MySQL.

*I'm providing this in case it may help:*

The `pos` values are in sequence **under each parent node (`parent_id`)**. So if we had another parent element "Bar" which had children "XX", "YY" and "ZZ", the data might look like this. Note what the `pos` values are.

So the query should only adjust the sequence of `pos` for a given `parent_id` at any particular time. In the previous example, I only want to reorder `pos` for `parent_id = 149` - assuming I was moving node "E".

```
id    |    parent_id    |    name    |     pos
--------------------------------------------------
149   |    NULL         |    Foo     |     0
150   |    149          |    A       |     0
151   |    149          |    B       |     1
152   |    149          |    C       |     2
153   |    149          |    D       |     3
154   |    149          |    E       |     4
155   |    149          |    F       |     5
906   |    NULL         |    Bar     |     0
907   |    906          |    XX      |     0
908   |    906          |    YY      |     1
909   |    906          |    ZZ      |     2
```

Comment: You should be able to use the moveUp and moveDown methods of the Tree behaviour? https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html#advanced-usage

Comment: I thought that as well, but it's not the case. We only have the `pos` value to work with, so we don't know the direction to move it in, or even the number of positions relative to where it was before it was moved. I spent a long time looking at that as well, but it's un-usable in this instance.

Comment: Have you tried using the method I've described in your last question? A column that holds the position seems redundant, as that is what the `lft` column can be used for.

Comment: @ndm no because where you said "determine the delta for `moveUp/Down()`" it wasn't clear at all how to do that. The link I've provided to GitHub shows the developer using both a `pos` field as well as `lft` and `rght` so I assume there's some reason for this. Also, you can't use `moveUp()` or `moveDown()` that Cake provides because you don't know which direction (up or down) the node has been moved in. All you know is its relative position beneath the parent - e.g. if the `pos` value is 2 it means its third in the list (third not second because of the 0 index).

Comment: You can determine the direction by substracting the current position (in the child node list) from the new position and checking whether the result is negative (move up) or positive (move down). I don't know why the developer chose to do what he did, but it's not necessary in order to be able to reorder a nested set, as it effectively just replicates what is already determined by the left value.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that. I've actually got it working now, finally! But I am using the `pos` field based on the accepted answer. I'll take a look into what you've said. The nice thing about having `pos` is that you can very easily see what position something is in when looking at the database. But I understand it's un-necessary to store it if it's possible to do this without that field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have enough information to modify the position of sibling nodes.

If 154 has been moved to position 2 with:

```
UPDATE tree SET pos = 2 WHERE id = 154 AND parent_id = 149;
```

We want to "remove" the node and then "insert" it back again. Something along these lines:

```
-- remove node from current position by updating nodes to the right to fill the gap
UPDATE tree SET pos = pos - 1 
       WHERE parent_id = 149 
       AND pos > (SELECT pos FROM tree WHERE id = 154);

-- insert node in new position by making space for it
UPDATE tree SET pos = pos + 1 WHERE parent_id = 149 AND pos >= 2;
UPDATE tree SET pos = 2 WHERE id = 154;
```

In general, for when you're moving nodes between parents:

```
:node_id       - id of node being moved
:new_parent_id - id of the new parent
:new_position  - new position


-- remove node from current position and update siblings to the right
UPDATE tree AS t
      JOIN tree AS n ON n.id = :node_id
      SET t.pos = t.pos - 1
      WHERE t.parent_id = n.parent_id AND t.pos > n.pos;

-- make space for new node under new parent
UPDATE tree
  SET pos = pos + 1
  WHERE parent_id = :new_parent_id
  AND pos >= :new_position;

-- update new position and new parent
UPDATE tree
  SET pos = :new_position, parent_id = :new_parent_id
  WHERE id = :node_id;
```

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate the help. The problem is that `pos + 1` works when you're moving a node further up. But what if you were to move "E" between "A" and "B"? We don't have any data about the direction in which anything has been moved. We would only know that "E" is now in position 1. If we apply your logic we'd get `A = 0, E = 1, B = 2, C  = 3, D = 4, F = 6`. Where is 5 - it's missing? Maybe we need to get the position of "E" prior to the move (5) and then do `pos-1` on higher elements? I'm lost with this now so can't think clearly, but you might be able to see something I can't?

Comment: Ok, my answer was incomplete the first time, thank you for pointing out the problem. It is easy to fix though, what you can do is first "remove" the node by updating the node positions to the right of it (if you picture this as a list) and then "insert" the node to a new position by updating its position and then increasing everything to the right of it's new location. Old parent_id and new parent_id of course can be different.

Answer (score 0):

the answer from Weltschmerz seems like it would work fine.

I would use a stored procedure however, renumbering them all, and just call it after 'dropping' the item into the new position.  Something like:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `renumberPos`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `renumberPos`(
  in itemID int,
  in parentID int,
  in mPos int
)
declare cnt int default 0;
declare n int default 0;
declare pk int;
declare cur CURSOR for select id from tree 
                       where parent_id = parentID 
                       and id != itemID
                       order by pos;
BEGIN
  select count(*) into n from tree where parent_id = parentID

  open cur;

  WHILE cnt <= n+1 DO
    IF cnt = mPos then
      FETCH cur into pk;
      update tree set 
      pos = cnt 
      where id = pk;
      cnt = cnt + 1;
    END IF;

    FETCH cur into pk;
    update tree set 
    pos = cnt 
    where id = pk;
    cnt = cnt + 1;
  END WHILE;

  close cur;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

then you would call it something like...

```
$sql = "CALL renumberPos($movedItemId, $itemParentID, $posMovedTo)";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
  echo "Procedure sorted the positions...";
}else{
  echo "ERROR: Couldn't execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```